# Multiple effects in functional component fails with server status code 500

Tags: react-hooks

This code, containing two effects, returns no data. However, when commenting out either one, data is returned normally.

When both effects are run, dev-tools network view shows `vehicleList` request headers 'Provisional' and `vendorList` with a status code of `500 Internal Server Error'.

Is it possible to request two effects in the same functional component? If yes, how?

PowMaintenance.js

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import { PowForm } from './PowForm';

const server = `http://${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACK_END_ADDRESS}:${
  process.env.REACT_APP_API_BACK_END_PORT
}`;

const PowMaintenance = () => {
  const [vehicleList, setVehicleList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(`${server}/api/vehicle/VehicleList`);
      setVehicleList(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const [vendorList, setVendorList] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(`${server}/api/vendor/VendorList`);
      setVendorList(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log('vehicle', vehicleList);
  console.log('vendor', vendorList);
  return (
    <div>
      <PowForm vendorList={vendorList} onChange={onChange} />
    </div>
  );
};

export { PowMaintenance };
```
````

Comment: There is nothing wrong with having multiple useEffect in a single component. Moreover, `500 Internal Server Error' is definitely an issue with server, not your frontend-code.

Comment: If this is so, why does each of the two useEffects process normally when the other is commented out?

Comment: I do not have a clue how your backend is working but he should return 4xx status if something wrong with your request, not 500. 500 means server got unhandled exception and it is  problem of backend

Answer (score 0):

Yozi, thank you for your help. You were correct, it was in the API. I researched it only because of your insistence.

A programming error in TDS/MSSQL involving connections.